# ALTER table column to timestamp now() properties

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I created a table in postgres from samples I found on the internet.  The definition of the column `stored` is:

```
stored  | timestamp without time zone | default '2014-04-11 21:19:20.144487'::timestamp without time zone
```

How do I alter this to be a "normal" timestamp now() type? So it will stamp the current date-time when inserting data?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `normal timestamp` ? PostgreSQL has the following date, time and timestamp types: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html please point to one which you consider "normal".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're trying to [change the default value](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-alter.html#AEN2780) . . .

```
alter table your-table-name
alter column stored set default current_timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

For changing the field type and default value the syntax will be ...

```
alter table your-table-name
alter column your-field type timestamp,
alter column your-field set default current_timestamp;
```